# In topology class, continuous and surjective problem

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:[0.1]\to [a,b]$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=b$. Prove that $f$ is surjective.

I don't know how to start this problem. Any hint or comment is welcome.

Comment: Do you know the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: For this type of problem you really need to mention what tools you have at your disposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the following theorem (from general topology):

Continuous functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ map connected sets to connected sets.

To prove that $f: [0,1]\to [a,b]$ is surjective you might argue by contradiction: Assume there was $y \in [a,b]$ such that $y \notin f([0,1])$. Then $U = (-\infty, y)\cap f([0,1])$ and $V= (y,\infty) \cap f([0,1])$ are two open sets in $f([0,1])$ such that $U \cap V = \varnothing$ and $U \cup V = f([0,1])$. This would mean that $f([0,1])$ is not connected, a contradiction.

Comment: Why are $U$ and $V$ open? For example, is $[a,y)$ closed in [a,b]? Where am I wrong?

Comment: @topy They are open by the definition of the subspace topology: If $Y$ is any subset of $\mathbb R$ then a set $S\subseteq Y$ in the subspace topology on $Y$ is defined to be open if there exists an open set $O \subseteq \mathbb R$ such that $S= Y \cap O$. Now in your question $Y$ is $f([0,1])$. Since $(y,\infty)$ is open in $\mathbb R$ the set $f([0,1]) \cap (y,\infty)$ is open in $f([0,1])$ (in the subspace topology).

Comment: @topy Regarding your question in the comment: If you endow $[a,b]$ with the subspace topology then $[a,y) = [a,b]\cap (-\infty,y)$ hence $[a,y)$ is open in $[a,b]$. It is not closed since if it was both closed and open we could write $[a,b]$ as a disjoint union of open sets which would contradict the fact that $[a,b]$ is connected.

Comment: It is very helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: @topy It was a pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is not surjective . Then there exists atleast a $x \in (a,b) $ which doesn't have a preimage in $(0,1)$ i.e there doesn't exist any $y \in (0,1) $ such that $f(y)=x$. But this would contradict the Intermediate value theorem which says that for any $x \in (a,b)$, there must exist a $y \in (0,1)$ such that $f(y) =x$.

Note: Intermediate value theorem holds good because $f$ is continuos

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, why everyone here wants to argue by contradiction? I personally don't like this.

So just say: f is surjective, since every point $x \in [a,b]$ is hit by the intermediate value theorem.

That's it.

(if you don't want to use analysis on this one you maybe need two sentences.)